# Weird error accessing an API that returns JSON string

Tags: json, vb.net

I get an error when executing the following code:

```
Public Function GetNumberInfo(ByVal pPhoneNumber As String) As PhoneInformation
    Dim url As String = "https://api.phonevalidator.com/api/v3/phonesearch?apikey=[My_API_Key]&phone=" & pPhoneNumber & "&type=fake,basic"
    DebugLog("App:Registration (RegistrationMOD.vb/GetNumberInfo) - DEBUG URL string: " & url)
    Dim request = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
    Dim myReader As StreamReader
    request.Method = "GET"
    request.Accept = "application/json"
    request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8;"

   ' The error occurs on the execution of this line.
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

    myReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
    Dim responseString As String = ""
    responseString = myReader.ReadToEnd
    Dim j As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim MyPhone As PhoneInformation = j.Deserialize(Of PhoneInformation)(responseString)
    Return MyPhone
End Function
```

The strange this is, this EXACT same code executes fine in a test console app I created to test my conversion from c# code to vb code.  I log all errors generated by the application and the following log entry details are what's in the log:

```
Debug log entries:
App:Registration/CreateAccount - An error occurred executing CheckPhone, the error is: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

App:Registration/CreateAccount - Phone number submitted: 7029270000

Trace: System.Net.WebException(0x80131509): The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Symbols.Container.InvokeMethod(Method   TargetProcedure, Object[] Arguments, Boolean[] CopyBack, BindingFlags Flags)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.ObjectLateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.NewLateBinding.LateGet(Object Instance, Type Type, String MemberName, Object[] Arguments, String[] ArgumentNames, Type[] TypeArguments, Boolean[] CopyBack)
   at Registration.RegistrationMod.GetNumberInfo(String pPhoneNumber) in C:\Users\Presc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Registration\Registration\RegistrationMod.vb:line 20
   at Registration.CreateAccount.CheckPhone(String pPhoneNumber) in C:\Users\Presc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Registration\Registration\CreateAccount.aspx.vb:line 241
Line:20 Filename: RegistrationMod.vb
Line:241 Filename: CreateAccount.aspx.vb
```

This error occurrs on the execution of the line:

```
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

The debug log entry generated for the url string generated by the app to be submitted to the API is:

```
App:Registration (RegistrationMOD.vb/GetNumberInfo) - DEBUG URL string: https://api.phonevalidator.com/api/v3/phonesearch?apikey=[My_API_Key]&phone=7029270000&type=fake,basic
```

I don't understand how it could work in the console app and not in this app.  The console app code is:

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net
Imports Nancy.Json

Module TestCodeMOD
    Public Function GetNumberInfo(ByVal pPhoneNumber As String) As PhoneInformation
        Dim url As String = "https://api.phonevalidator.com/api/v3/phonesearch?apikey=[My_API_Key]&phone=" & pPhoneNumber & "&type=fake,basic"
        Dim request = CType(WebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
        Dim myReader As StreamReader
        request.Method = "GET"
        request.Accept = "application/json"
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8;"
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        myReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)
        Dim responseString As String = ""
        responseString = myReader.ReadToEnd
        Dim j As JavaScriptSerializer = New JavaScriptSerializer()
        Dim MyPhone As PhoneInformation = j.Deserialize(Of PhoneInformation)(responseString)
        Return MyPhone
    End Function
End Module
```

I execute the function like so:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim MyPhone As PhoneInformation
    MyPhone = GetNumberInfo("7029270000")
End Sub
```

The console app executes without any errors and populates the `PhoneInformation` class instance with the expected data.  I'm at a loss as to what's going on and I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: What is the *other application* where the code that fails is executed? What .NET versions are the two apps targeting? Are you running both in the same machine? If not, what Systems' versions?

Comment: The registration app runs on Windows Server 2012 R2, the test app (console) I run on my laptop, latest version of Windows 11.  Both were created using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019
Version 16.7.12, both were compiled with the same version of the Nancy.JSON plugin and NewtonSoft.JSON plugin.  I've gone over each line to ensure that each object was instantiated the same way.  Not one difference.  I'm still playing with it, but haven't gotten anywhere thus far.

Comment: The problem is `Windows Server 2012 R2`. You also didn't mention the target .NET version, the VS version is irrelevant -- Try first to add, before anything else, `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12`. You need at least .NET Framework 4.5.2 -- If that doesn't work, you may not have required Cipher Suites in the 2012 R2 System, which is not surprising

Comment: Ah, yes.  Both machines are .NET Framework 4.8.  But, I think you may have put me on the right path.  Web.config.  I'll let you know.

Comment: You may also try to call, after the ServicePointManager thing,         `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = Function(snd As Object, Cert As X509Certificate, Chain As X509Chain, Err As SslPolicyErrors) Return True End Function` (on 3 lines) -- But wrong protocol version and/or missing Cipher Suites are the most probable cause (because of the response error)